# sp_executesql parameter not recognized

Tags: sql-server-2012, ado.net

I have a storedProcedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Employee_GetEmployeeByID
    @employeeID int 
AS
    select EM.EmployeeID,EM.FullName, GM.Gender,EM.PhoneNumber
    from EmployeesMaster EM
    JOIN GenderMaster GM ON EM.GenderID = GM.GenderID
    where (EM.EmployeeID = @employeeID )
```

I'm trying to execute (generated by ado.net code)

```
exec sp_executesql N'Employee_GetEmployeeByID',N'@employeeID int',@employeeID=7
```

But, I'm getting an error like

```
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure Employee_GetEmployeeByID, Line 0
Procedure or function 'Employee_GetEmployeeByID' expects parameter '@employeeID', which was not supplied.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the variable first?

`DECLARE @employeeID int = 7
exec sp_executesql N'Employee_GetEmployeeByID',N'@employeeID int',@employeeID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

Syntax :

```
EXEC Procedure_Name Parameters
```

Example :

```
DECLARE @empid int = 5
EXEC Employee_GetEmployeeByID @empid
```